# Mac 10.8 bash_profile work weird

Tags: macos, export

I follow some "setup cocos2dx and android on mac" tutorial. When I come to setup .bash_profile, I am ask to create .bash_profile and edit:

```
export COCOS2DX_ROOT=~/Documents/Cocos2dx/cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/Documents/Android/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/Users/Documents/Android/android-ndk-r8e
export NDK_ROOT=/Users/Documents/Android/android-ndk-r8e
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}
```

after restart terminal:

```
echo $COCOS2DX_ROOT
export/AS/Documents/Cocos2dx/cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2
cd $COCOS2DX_ROOT
export: No such file or directorycos2dx/cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2
```

I have no idea how the "export" go into the path. I have tried "~/..." and "/User/..."(full path). But all go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the lines got entered into your `.bash_profile` incorrectly - it looks like maybe a newline got removed somehow. Edit your `.bash_profile` again and ensure that it looks like what you posted above. Save and restart your terminal session, and you should be OK.

Comment: you are right, I follow a tutorial and use "open -e .bash_profile" to open editor and edit.
When I use vi to open, all "newline" become "^M" and goes wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: @user1295050 can you tell me which link you followed to solve this issue .. i am also facing same kind of problem .. like this              /Volumes/DATA-D/cocos2d-x/samples/Cpp/TestCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh: line 95: /ndk-build: No such file or directory